# Proving $A' \cup B'=(A \cup B)'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Duplicate to: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498904/derived-sets-prove-a-cup-b-a-cup-b)

My approach: Let $x \in A' \cup B' \implies x \in A'$ or $x \in B'$. Hence, in either case, $(N'_\epsilon  (x) \cap A) \cup (N'_\epsilon  (x) \cap B)= N'_\epsilon  (x) \cap (A \cup B) \neq \emptyset\ , \forall  \epsilon>0.$

Therefore, $A' \cup B' \subset (A \cup B)' $

Again, $x \in (A \cup B)' \implies N'_\epsilon(x) \cap (A\cup B) \neq \emptyset  \implies$ either  $N'_\epsilon(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset $ or $N'_\epsilon(x) \cap B \neq \emptyset $. Therefore, $x \in A' \cup B'  $

Hence, we are done.

Kindly verify this.

Comment: Please use `$\emptyset$` instead of `$\phi$`.

Comment: Or,you can use  `$\varnothing$` $\varnothing$.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, an edit has been made.

Comment: Isn't this wrong? I think you are referring to De Morgan's law.

Comment: i am referring to derived sets in point set topology

Comment: @prog_SAHIL I thought the same, but the proclaimed duplicate gives more context. I still think that the context should be included here.

Comment: @Biswas  Pardon my ignorance.  What is a "derived set"?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, Yes. It just starts like '*prove this*' without any proper context as to what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is wrong: you just conclude that *either* $N'_\epsilon(x)\cap A\ne\emptyset$ *or* $N'_\epsilon(x)\cap B\ne\emptyset$, but this doesn't show that either $x\in A'$ or $x\in B'$.

Indeed, showing that $x\in A'\cup B'$ requires proving that,

> (for every $\epsilon>0$, $N'_\epsilon(x)\cap A\ne\emptyset$) or (for every $\epsilon>0$, $N'_\epsilon(x)\cap B\ne\emptyset$)

which is different from what you proved.

---

Suppose $x\in (A\cup B)'$, but $x\notin A'$. Let's show that necessarily $x\in B'$. Fix $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $N'_{\epsilon_0}(x)\cap A=\emptyset$.

Hence, for every $0<\delta<\epsilon_0$, $N'_\delta(x)\cap A=\emptyset$. From the assumption $x\in(A\cup B)'$, we deduce that $N'_\delta(x)\cap(A\cup B)\ne\emptyset$, so $N'_\delta(x)\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

Let $\epsilon>0$; take $\delta<\min\{\epsilon,\epsilon_0\}$. Then
$$
\emptyset\ne N'_\delta(x)\cap B\subseteq N'_\epsilon(x)\cap B
$$
This proves $x\in B'$.

Comment: A beautiful proof indeed. The answer is similar to that of the included duplicate.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas I didn't look at that; the important part of the answer was the analysis of your attempt.

Comment: My methodology was the following : let us consider the following infinite intersections of neighbourhoods and either of the set, $[N'_{\epsilon_1}(x) \cap N'_{\epsilon_2}(x) \cap ...N'_{\epsilon_n}(x) \cap A]=A_k$ where $ n \rightarrow  \infty$. Now, everything reduces to $A_k \cup B_k \neq \emptyset$. Due to the consideration of infinite intersection, either one of the intersection, say $A_k$, has to be zero (in some cases, both are non-zero) , hence the point $x$ must be in $B_k$, i.e, $x$ is in $B'$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas It's the same error: you need to show that either every $N'_\epsilon(x)$ intersects $A$ or every $N'_\epsilon(x)$ intersects $B$. It's not sufficient to show that each $N'_\epsilon(x)$ intersects either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: are you implying that there is a possibility of "periodic exclusion and inclusion" of $N'_\epsilon(x)$ with $A$ and $B$ individually?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas Precisely. It doesn't happen, but your argument doesn't show it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81288/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-egreg).